# Check if shared libraries are compatible with a binary?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

**Background**:I have a large project which links dozens of shared libraries, both from external sources and from our own projects. Before delivery of a new software version I usually do `make clean all` and roll out all the executables and shared libraries which come with the project.

Now it happens sometimes that a client prefers to have only an executable shipped, e.g. for a hot-fix, because their regulations require to test all affected functionality when changing a library, which means everything.

**Question**:
What is the simplest way to decide if an executable is compatible to a set of shared libraries?

---

Edit: My current approach is "If the headers of the libs have not changed it will be compatible", but that is an error prone approach and I would rather check the executable and libraries themselves.

Comment: 1) well-designed interfaces 2) Tests

Comment: Welcome to ABI hell. You cannot really test this sort of stuff reliably. You need to guarantee ABI stability for your shared libraries and watch out for that religiously.

Comment: @KerrekSB can you give recommendations on how to guarantee ABI stability?

Comment: https://www.sourceware.org/libabigail/ contains tools for checking binary compatibility, and https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B is a good set of rules

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you for the links. If you post them as an answer I will accept.

Comment: I got downvoted to -7 earlier today for an answer that was just two links ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/). It's a tool to check binary compatibility of library versions. Developed since 2009.

If you have debug info of your libraries available somewhere then you can also try [abi-dumper](https://github.com/lvc/abi-dumper):

```
# Create ABI dumps from debug info
abi-dumper libSample-1.0.so.debug -o ABI-1.0.dump
abi-dumper libSample-2.0.so.debug -o ABI-2.0.dump

# Compare ABI dumps
abi-compliance-checker -l libSample -old ABI-1.0.dump -new ABI-2.0.dump
```

Answer (score 1):

The [libabigail](https://www.sourceware.org/libabigail/) project contains tools for checking binary compatibility, and [Binary compatibility issues with C++](https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B) is a good set of rules.